# Prove that angles are equal using complex numbers

Tags: geometry, triangles

that in triangle $\Delta ABC$, where $D$ is a point on side $BC$, $E$ is a point on side $AB$, $BD=AC$, $AD=AE$ and $AB^2=AC\cdot BC$: angle $BAD$ is equal to angle $CEA$. This problem can be quite easily solved using elementary geometry, but I'm interested in other, more interesting methods, like using complex numbers. Or analytic geometry. If it is possible this way.

Comment: *This problem can be quite easily solved using elementary geometry* - How ?

Comment: @Luican by showing two similarities, $\dfrac{AB}{BD}=\dfrac{BC}{AB}$ so $\Delta ABD \sim \Delta CBA$, again by writing another feature of this similarity we'd have $\dfrac{AD}{BD}=\dfrac{AC}{AB}\Rightarrow \dfrac{AE}{AC}=\dfrac{AC}{AB} \Rightarrow \Delta AEC\sim \Delta ACB$